# Groupby with row index operation?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

How can I select the rows with given row index operation (say, only even rows or only if row# % 5 == 0) in pandas?
let's say I have a dataframe with df `[120 rows x 10 column]`, and I want to create two out of it, one from even rows df1 `[60 rows x 10 column]`, and one from odd rows `[60 rows x 10 column]`?

Comment: You can just do `df.iloc[::2]` and `df.iloc[1::2]` to slice the dfs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice the dfs using normal list style slicing semantics:

```
first = df.iloc[::2]
second = df.iloc[1::2]
```

So the first steps every 2 rows starting from first to last row
the second does the same but starts from row 1, the second row, and steps every 2 rows

Comment: totally forgot I can just use slicing. The only problem with this code, the 0th element for some reason is included in both resulting dataframes.

Comment: UPD: the 0th element was a problem with my code! the file was read incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

As stated already, you may use iloc

```
df0 = df.iloc[::2]
df1 = df.iloc[1::2]
```

If you have a more complex selection schema you may pass a boolean vector to iloc, e.g.,

```
def filter_by( idx ):
    # param idx: an index
    # returns True if idx%4==0 or idx%4==1
    if idx%4==0 or idx%4==1:
        return True
    else:
        return False    

# a boolean vector is created by means of filter_by
df_new = df.iloc[ [ filter_by(i) for i in range(df.shape[0]) ] ]
```

the filtering above is then:

```
df0 = df.iloc[ [ idx%2==0 for idx in range(df.shape[0]) ] ]
df1 = df.iloc[ [ idx%2==1 for idx in range(df.shape[0]) ] ]
```